# Excel OR function doesn't allow spill range?

Tags: excel, spill-range

how do i get OR function to return a spill range?

For example, in excel 365, cell A1 and B1, I have a spill range of sequence(20). Which creates 2 sequence of 1-20. In c1, I tried to put in "=OR(A1#>1,B1#>1)". I would expect a result of 20 rows with first being false and other being true. But the result only return TRUE in c2. any idea how i can populate the entire column?

TIA!

Comment: i was able to solve this with "=IF(A1#>1,TRUE,IF(B1#>1,TRUE))". but can I accomplish this by directly using OR?

Comment: No.  `OR` is used to determine if **any** conditions in a test are TRUE.  As such, it only returns a single value.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, boolean results can be used as numbers where True=1 and False=0. So, for `OR` operations you can use + and for `AND` operations you can use *.

In your case you could write `=(A1#>1)+(B1#>1)>0` if in need of OR. For `AND` you can rewrite as `=(A1#>1)*(B1#>1)>0`

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to achieve this if you have Office365 using `BYROW`.
As mentioned in comments, `OR` returns a single value for an entire range, and a spilled array formula counts as a single range. The `BYROW` function splits a range into rows and applies another function to each row individually.
Applied to your question:

```
=BYROW(A1#:B1#, LAMBDA(row, OR(row>1)))
```

I understand that this isn't really much more efficient *in this instance* than the solution you already have working, but hopefully the knowledge could help you or someone in a situation with more complex arguments to pass (e.g. many OR conditions to check).